# How to substitute null or 0 back into Oracle View when certain criteria are met

Tags: sql, oracle

so I am trying to display my 'original values' (before some data cleansing process I wrote was run) in a view Whenever the **'CHANGE_CODE'** column is marked with '**NE**' or '**NI**', I need to grab the value that is correlated to the same **Color**, **Car** and **Timestamp** (this will be the Composite Key) but need the **change_code** = '*ORIG*' or '*ORIG2* (depending on what the change_code correlated to the non-flagged value/ entry is) .

***What I have originally:***

```
VAL      COLOR       TIMESTAMP                    CAR          CHANGE_CODE
NULL     Blue        10/16/2018 01:00 AM EST      BMW          NE
7        Blue        10/16/2018 01:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
20       Blue        10/16/2018 02:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
 0       Blue        10/16/2018 02:00 AM EST      BMW          NE
15       Blue        10/16/2018 03:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
22       Blue        10/16/2018 04:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
23       Blue        10/16/2018 05:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
```

***What my end result should look like:***

```
VAL      COLOR       TIMESTAMP                    CAR          CHANGE_CODE
NULL     Blue        10/16/2018 01:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
 0       Blue        10/16/2018 02:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG 
15       Blue        10/16/2018 03:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
22       Blue        10/16/2018 04:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
23       Blue        10/16/2018 05:00 AM EST      BMW          ORIG
```

***What I've tried:***

```
select
       CASE WHEN change_code IN ('NE', NI')
            THEN MIN_VAL
            ELSE VAL
             END                VAL
     , color
     , timestamp
     , car
     , change_code
  from table
  join (select min(val) as MIN_VAL
             , color
             , timestamp
             , car
          from table
          group by COLOR, TIMESTAMP, CAR
        ) subq on table.color = subq.color AND table.timestamp = subq.timestamp AND table.car = subq.car;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data you have provided and the logic you have described, you can do this with aggregation:

```
select (case when sum(case when change_code in ('NI', 'NE') then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when change_code in ('NI', 'NE') then val end)
             else max(val)
        end) as val
       color, timestamp, car,
       max(case when change_code not in ('NI', 'NE') then change_code end) as change_code
from t
group by color, timestamp, car;
```

Comment: for the last column of your select did you mean to put VAL instead of change_code? Otherwise we have two 'change_codes' in the query :(

Comment: also, I noticed that the max(Val) in line #3 is grabbing the number rather than the null or 0. do you know if we can grab the null or 0 instead?

Comment: @JohnWick . . . That should only be occurring when there is no change (the outer `case` expression).